# DataGridView showing some extra space after last row

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `Panel` control on which I have placed a `DataGridView` control, showing data from SQL server. It works perfectly except that there is an unnecessary space appearing when I move the scrollbar to the bottom. I shortened the height, but the space still stays there.

[image]

My `DataGridView` was programatically created like:

```
_myDgv = new DataGridView();
_myDgv.Width = 300;
_myDgv.Height = 500;
_myDgv.Top = 20;
_myDgv.Left = 20;
_myDgv.RowHeadersVisible = false; 
_myDgv.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
_myDgv.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;  
_myDgv.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
_myDgv.RowTemplate.Height = 30;
_myDgv.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
_myDgv.AllowUserToResizeRows = false; 
_myDgv.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None;
_myPanel.Controls.Add(_myDgv);
```

Can someone tell me how to get rid of the space below the last row when the scrollbar is at the bottom?

Comment: That is the datagrid workspace right there. You want the datagrid to autoresize so it doesn´t show that gray space?

Comment: Your'e setting scroll bars to none on the datagrid.  Are your sure that scroll bar is for the data grid and that the space in question is part of the data grid?

Comment: Yes somehow I am still getting the scroll bar from this DataGridView. And shortening the height of this control did not take away the space there..