# DataGridView - extra grey space after last row

Tags: c#, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I have a DataGridView with two columns. After the last row I have some gray space. It is exactly the same problem here but it is unsolved [DataGridView showing some extra space after last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46736475/datagridview-showing-some-extra-space-after-last-row)

How can I get rid of this extra gray space on the bottom?

Edit: Here you can download preview that I am talking about:
https://github.com/pr0s3q/DataGridViewError

[Unwanted grey space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ooid.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Whole code is available in github link

Answer (score 0):

The problem got fixed by changing datagridview height.
My images have 85px height, so I need to fit specific number of them (i.e. 4, not 3.5)
So 85x4 = 340, adding inner margins, I need to have 347px height in order to not see this ugly gray space